# Method 'set_Description' in type 'myAssembly.NetProduct' from assembly 'myAssembly' does not have an implementation

Tags: vb.net, interface, properties, vb6

I have a DLL file created in VB6. It contains a class named `Product` and that contains the following simple code:

```
Option Explicit

Private sDescription As String

Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = sDescription
End Property

Public Property Let Description(Value As String)
    sDescription = Value
End Property
```

I want to use this DLL in VB.NET, which is nothing more than registering the DLL on my system and including the DLL file in the references. Visual Studio automatically generates an interop DLL to consume the COM DLL. This interop DLL generates interfaces for all classes. In VB.NET I want to create a new class that implements the `Product` interface from the interop DLL. So I code:

```
Imports myAssembly

Public Class NetProduct
    Implements myAssembly.Product

    Public Property Description As String Implements _Product.Description
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The property is auto-generated because I implemented the `Product` interface. But here comes the problem because when I start using the `NetProduct` class I get an error telling me this:

> Method 'set_Description' in type 'myProject.NetProduct' from
> assembly 'myProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

The problem is that there is no method `set_Description` in the interface. When I view the definition of the `Product` interface it shows me the following:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace myAssembly
    <CoClass(GetType(ProductClass))> <Guid("49CE2F98-931C-441B-B322-9F39B6D6F212")>
    Public Interface Product
        Implements _Product
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

The definition of the `_Product` interface is:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace myAssembly
    <Guid("49CE2F98-931C-441B-B322-9F39B6D6F212")> <TypeLibTypeAttribute(4304)>
    Public Interface _Product <DispId(1745027072)>
        Property Description As String
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

When I use the interface `myAssembly.Product` directly to create a new object then everything works as you would expect. The property does not pose a problem there. But when I implement the interface in a .NET class the problem arises.

How do I solve this?

**[update 1]** After creating a method Set_Description I see [the following error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc31060) appear:

> property 'Description' implicitly defines 'set_Description', which
> conflicts with a member of the same name in class 'NetProduct'.

This must have something to do with my problem, although I don't know what it is. I already tried completing the property to make sure the `Throw New NotImplementedException()` wouldn't be in the way but that didn't make the error go away. My code builds just fine by the way. The error I gave earlier is a runtime error. Not a build error.

```
Private myDescription As String

Public Property Description As String Implements Product.Description
    Get
        Return myDescription
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        myDescription = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**[update 2]** I have used JetBrains DotPeek to disassemble the interop.dll that Visual Studio generates. Disassembly is coded in C#. It contains 2 interfaces and 1 class for the single `Product` class from VB6. Here are all details.

I'll start with the `Product` class itself.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myAssembly
{
  [ClassInterface(0)]
  [Guid("C54B96A8-1499-4B76-8508-0B732E551326")]
  [TypeLibType(2)]
  [ComImport]
  public class ProductClass : _Product, Product
  {
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    public extern ProductClass();

    [DispId(1745027072)]
    public virtual extern string Description { [DispId(1745027072), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] get; [DispId(1745027072), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), In, Out] set; }
  }
}
```

The `ProductClass` uses 2 interfaces. I don't understand why because one of those is just an implementation of the other. This is the `Product` interface.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myAssembly
{
  [CoClass(typeof (ProductClass))]
  [Guid("49CE2F98-931C-441B-B322-9F39B6D6F212")]
  [ComImport]
  public interface Product : _Product
  {
  }
}
```

And then we have the `_Product` interface. They even share the same Guid. It might have something to do with backwards compatibility.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myAssembly
{
  [Guid("49CE2F98-931C-441B-B322-9F39B6D6F212")]
  [TypeLibType(4304)]
  [ComImport]
  public interface _Product
  {
    [DispId(1745027072)]
    string Description { [DispId(1745027072), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] get; [DispId(1745027072), MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)] [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), In, Out] set; }
  }
}
```

This is all I could find. Still no clue where the error for `Set_Description` comes from.

**[Update 3] Example code**

The code for the VB6 class is on top of this question. Nothing fancy there. The code for testing implementation in .NET is like this:

```
Imports myAssembly

Public Class NetProduct
    Implements myAssembly.Product

    Private myDescription As String

    Public Property Description As String Implements Product.Description
        Get
            Return myDescription
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            myDescription = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

To test the `NetProduct` class I dropped a `Button` on a `Form` and create an instance of the class when the button is being clicked.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click '<- Error happens here, so on loading the datatype!
    Dim Product As New NetProduct 'Error does NOT happen here.
End Sub
```

The whole project compiles without errors. The project even runs without errors UNTIL you click the button. Probably because the `NetProduct` type is first loaded on that point.

Comment: The really interesting part is this: "I already tried completing the property to make sure the Throw New NotImplementedException() wouldn't be in the way but that didn't make the error go away."  Everything else is exactly what I would expect based on how properties are implemented under the hood.  Did you try debugging?

Comment: @Craig Debugging stops at the start of the method where my `NetProduct` class comes in play. It's an `System.TypeLoadException` so the actual class isn't even used in that part of the code.

Comment: Have you tried disassembling your assembly using ildasm?  Or looked at it in e.g. ILSpy?  (I'm spit-balling here trying to find something that might give a clue as to what's failing / how.)

Comment: @Craig See update 2 for the disassembled interop code. That is the code where the interface comes from. Spoiler alert: no weird methods there. Just the code you would expect.

Comment: What I find kinda weird - which you already stated yourself in update 2 - is that `Interface Product` should implement `Interface _Product`, but hasn't any actual implementation. Out of curiosity: which VS.NET version do you use? I have the feeling that it may bork the automatic InterOp creation for some reason.

Comment: @HelO'Ween I use Visual Studio Professional 2019 (version 16.11.9).

Comment: I don't have VS 2019 installed, but just added one of our VB6 COM DLLs to a VS 2017 project. No Interop DLLS created for that. If I `Import OurCOMDll` and then `Implements OurCOMDll.AClassFromIt` and let VS created the stub properties/methods, no complaints there, compiles just fine. Does your VB6 DLL perhaps use that awkward VB6 `Implements` feature?

Comment: @HelO'Ween My solution also compiles just fine. The problem occurs only at runtime. About that VB6 `Implements` feature, I have no idea what that is so I don't think I'm using that.

Comment: I tried to figure out where/why that Interop DLL you mentioned got generated. That didn't happen for me (with VS 2017).

Comment: @HelO'Ween So if you add your VB6 DLL to VS2017 you don't see it as `interop.OurCOMDll.dll`? Because that is what I get when I add VB6 DLL's.

Comment: My bad, it ofc does _(tomatoes -> eyes)_. Did another test project, this time not only compiling, put setting/getting a `String` property of a class from that COM DLL, worked as expected. How do you access/view that definition you posted? From the Object Browser -> "Browse definition" for that class, I only get the regular listing of properties/methods. Another thing worth mentioning perhaps: our DLL has _no_ UI components. Though it itself references a bunch of other COM DLLs (e.g. MSXML, Crystal Reports) for which VS 2017 also generates project references and COM Interop DLLs.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Check my Update 3 in the question. That is the code I'm using to create the class based on the interop interface. The button handles the actual test at runtime.

Comment: Martin, just to check, did you do a full clean and rebuild of ALL the DLLs involved here?

Answer (score 0):

I used a console app to do my test. Other than that, my VB.NET code is basically identical to yours in update 3. The VB.NET properties were auto-generated by VS with the stub `Throw New NotImplementedException()` after using the `Implements` statement :

```
Imports OurCOMDll

Class TestClass
   Implements OurCOMDll.ClassInCOMDll

   Dim msStringProperty As String = String.Empty

   Public Property StringProperty As String Implements _ClassInCOMDll.StringProperty
      Get
         StringProperty= msStringProperty
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
         msStringProperty = value
      End Set
   End Property

End Class

Module Module1

   Sub Main()

      Dim o As New OurCOMDll.ClassInCOMDll

      o.StringProperty = "Hello World!"

      Console.WriteLine(o.StringProperty) ' Outputs 'Hello World!' as expected

      Console.ReadLine()

   End Sub

End Module
```

Same is true for the VB6 code. The string property is implemented like yours.
Distinguishing factors so far:

- VS 2019 vs. VS 2017
- (Consuming) GUI vs. Console application
- Different property names

Comment: *For C# projects* - referencing a COM dll definitely did result in an interop DLL being created for me back in VS2015, and I think VS2017 as well. Maybe it doesn't do it the same way for a VB project??

Comment: You are making a mistake here. `Dim o As New OurCOMDll.ClassInCOMDll` should be `Dim o As New TestClass`. You're not using your .NET class at all in this test. And THAT is where the error should be. Please check if your code runs fine with the change I suggested.

Comment: You're right _:facepalm:_. But I _think_ I found the solution. I created the Interop DLL as described [here](https://www.developerdrive.com/make-legacy-vb-6-components-work-with-net-applications/). Then I added the resulting DLL as a reference to the project. I used the same code as above, except for replacing `Dim o As New OurCOMDll.ClassInCOMDll` with `Dim o As New OurClass`. That did the trick for me.

Comment: @HelO'Ween I created the wrapper DLL as you suggested with your link. The wrapper came out fine but the same error remains. Too bad. Really had my hopes up.

Comment: One (last?) thing you can try: create a dedicated x86 Release/Debug configuration, i.e. not the default _AnyCPU_. A VB6 COM DLL obviously is 32-bit only.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Tested it for 32-bit only but it didn't work either.